# Calculating $(1 + i)^{2n}$ according to the values of $n$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ Calculating the expression $(1 + i)^{2n}$ according to the values of $n$
>
> - I'm interested in more ways of Calculating  it

---

**My thoughts**

\begin{align}
i^0 &{}= 1, \quad &
i^1 &{}= i, \quad &
i^2 &{}= -1, \quad &
i^3 &{}= -i, \\
i^4 &={} 1, \quad &
i^5 &={} i, \quad &
i^6 &{}= -1, \quad &
i^7 &{}= -i,\\
\forall k\geq 0 \qquad 
i^{4k} &{}= 1, \quad &
i^{4k+1} &{}= i, \quad &
i^{4k+2} &{}= -1, \quad &
i^{4k+3} &{}= -i, \\
\end{align}

note that it goes round in circles then the complexe sequence $(i^{n})_{n\geq 0}$ periodic with period $4$

$$i^{4+n}=i^{n}$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\qquad i^{n}\in \{-1,1,-i,i  \}$$

\begin{align}
(1+i)^2&=2i\\
(1+i)^{2n}&=(2i)^{n}=2^{n}i^{n}
\end{align}

note that :
$$n \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \iff 4/n \iff \exists k \in\mathbb{N}\quad n=4k\\
  n \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \iff 4/n-1 \iff \exists k \in\mathbb{N}\quad n=4k+1\\
  n \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \iff 4/n-2 \iff \exists k \in\mathbb{N}\quad n=4k+2\\
  n \equiv 3 \pmod{4} \iff 4/n-3 \iff \exists k \in\mathbb{N}\quad n=4k+3\\ $$

\begin{align}
 \text{ then if } 4\mid n-1  &{} \text{ then } n=4k+1 ,\quad  i^{n}=i \\
\text{ then if } 4\mid n-2 &{} \text{ then } n=4k+2 ,\quad  i^{n}=-1 \\
\text{ then if } 4\mid n-3 &{} \text{ then } n=4k+3 ,\quad  i^{n}=-i
\end{align}

$$i^{n}=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,} \\ i &\mbox{if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$,}  \\-1 &\mbox{if $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$},  \\ -i  &\mbox{if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$}. \end{cases}$$
then
$$(1+i)^{2n}=\begin{cases} 2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,} \\ i\cdot2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$,}  \\-2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$},  \\ -i \cdot 2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$}. \end{cases}$$

---

- Is my proof correct
- I'm interested in more ways of Calculating it

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Binomial formula?

Comment: $(1+i)^{2n} = ((1+i)^2)^n = (2i)^n = 2^ni^n$

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the expression modulo $4$: $$(1+i)^{2n}=\begin{cases} 2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,} \\ i\cdot2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$,}  \\-2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$},  \\ -i \cdot 2^n &\mbox{if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$}. \end{cases}$$

I am not sure if this is what you're question is asking though?

Answer (score 1):

Using Euler identity, $$(1+i)^{2n}=2^n \, \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+i \,2^n \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)$$